# Como hago algo case sensitive en Python?

Tags: python-3.x

¿Cómo hago para que cuando se inserte REGLA o jhon se imprima el mensaje?

```
user_names = { regla, JHON}
new_usernames = input("Insert your username")
for new_username in new_usernames :
    If new_username in user_name:
    print("thas username is already taken ")
```

Comment: ¿Por qué estás iterando sobre new_usernames? ¿Qué estás guardando ahí?

Comment: Lo siento no entiendo tu pregunta, hablas de como hacer "algo" case sensitive, después, realizas otra pregunta sobre REGLA o jhon que no tiene nada que ver con el título de la pregunta y por último dejas un trozo de código en el que no explicas ni lo que haces, ni cual es el  resultado esperado. Por favor mejora tu pregunta para que podamos ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando letras mayúsculas y minúsculas son tratadas como distintas (case-sensitive) o equivalentes (case-insensitive):

```
#Para que sea case sensitive
user_names = { 'regla', 'JHON'}
new_username = input("Insert your username")
if new_username in user_names:
    print("1 thas username is already taken ")

#Para que sea case insensitive
user_names1 = { 'regla', 'JHON'}
new_username1 = input("Insert your username")
for n in user_names1:
    if n.lower() == new_username1.lower():
        print("2 thas username is already taken ")

#Para que sea case insensitive
user_names2 = { 'regla', 'JHON'}
new_username2 = input("Insert your username")
if new_username2.upper() in map(str.upper, user_names2):
    print("3 thas username is already taken ")

#Para que sea case insensitive
user_names3 = { 'regla', 'JHON'}
new_username3 = input("Insert your username")
if new_username3.upper() in (name.upper() for name in user_names3):
    print("4 thas username is already taken ")
```